# How to retrieve a record from android database by click on Search button?

Tags: android, database, search

I have started coding for `Finder` app which contains employee records and user will able to find employee record by using 'id' when click on Search button in useractivity.java and data should display in Empdetails.java activity in textview contains 3 textfields to display. Below is my code , Please help me in this

My requirement : I want to retrieve a single record by giving an **id** in UserActivity.java and when i click on Search button it should get a record details in Empdetails.java in text view

Output:

id: 12345

name : vijay kumar

Email: vijay@gmail.com

like above shown

Thanks inadvance
Vijay Kumar.

1) AdminActivity.java

```
public class AdminActivity extends Activity {

String id,name,email;
SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("EMP",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EMP(id varchar,name varchar,email varchar);");
}

public void Submit(View view)
{       
EditText edittext1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.id);
    EditText edittext2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    EditText edittext3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    id=edittext1.getText().toString();
    name=edittext2.getText().toString();
    email=edittext3.getText().toString();
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO EMP(id,name,email) values ('"+id+"','"+name+"','"+email+"');");

    if(id.equals("") && name.equals("") && email.equals(""))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter details and submit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else 
        if(id.equals(""))
       {
            Toast toast=new Toast (getApplicationContext());
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter id....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    else
        if(name.equals(""))
           {
            Toast toast=new Toast (getApplicationContext());
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Name....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        else
             if(email.equals(""))
            {
            Toast toast=new Toast (getApplicationContext());
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email.....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
             else 
                { 
                    Toast toast=new Toast (getApplicationContext());
                    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    edittext1.setText("");
                    edittext2.setText("");
                    edittext3.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data submitted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    db.close();
                 }
            }

public void Exit(View view){
    System.exit(0);
}

}
```

2) UserAvtivity.java

```
public class UserActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);
    }

    public void Search(View view)
    {
    /////???????????????
    }

    public void Exit(View view)
    {
    System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place an editText on UserActivity class for id search. and on onClickListener of a Button using sql query retrieve data from database (SELECT * From tableName where id = (Here put id no where user is going to search for))and display it in a listview.
For simple example use this reference.
http://javapapers.com/android/android-sqlite-database/

Comment: Could you please provide the code for Search button in the "question mark" field  in the above my question??

Answer (score 0):

I will explain the logical method to do this:

You will need to check the ID you get from the user, and compare this ID with *each* ID stored in the database. Once you find a match, you should collect all the details under that ID. So for this you will require a **readable** database, and then try to collect the information using a **Cursor**.

Check this for further info: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Write all this code *within* the *onClick()* method of your search button.

**EDIT:** Code to include the above functionality in *onClick()* event:

```
search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //Include your code here
        }   
     });
```

Also create a search button in your **layout** and instantiate it using

```
 private Button search = null; // This line inside your MainActivity class
 search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search); //This line inside onCreate function.
```

As for the code to actually implement that logic, check the link i gave you and try coding it on you own.

Comment: Hi Gautham,  could you please provide code for Search button in UserActivity.java ? as i didn't get any idea on that.....

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Class for creating the Database and doing queries/selects, inserts and updates.

It will bi nice to separate your SQL script - use String variables

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EMP(id varchar, name varchar, email varchar);";
```

to insert data use db.insert , select db.select or **rawQuery**. You need to use **Cursor** to retrieve the data from the DB query. After getting the data from the **Cursor** you can arrange it as you wish.

```
private static final String SELECT_ID = "SELECT name, mail FROM EMP WHERE id = ? ;";
```

Your DB id must be INTEGER and not a varchar - it is a Primary Key or ? 
Primary Key: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key
SQLite Tuts: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/index.htm

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Code for the Search

```
Button search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_search);
search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // DO queries, Update TextView or call your methods
         }
     });
```

This is bad:

```
id=edittext1.getText().toString();
name=edittext2.getText().toString();
email=edittext3.getText().toString();
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO EMP(id,name,email) values ('"+id+"','"+name+"','"+email+"');");
```

It will be nice first to check the data and then to insert it into the Database.

```
 if(email.lenght() > 0 ){
 // check other data, do things
 }
```

Comment: Hi john, i don't know coding part in java, i belonged to oracle DBA but i'm interested in java coding i have to submit this in MS project so could you please tell me code for search and code for  checking before inserting repeated data???? please help me in this coding part.......

Comment: please tell me your mail id i'll mail to you my entire code and please go through and let me know the mistakes in my coding part

Comment: no need to mail it, post it here, so many users can help you. sorry for the late answer.